# Import multiple CSV files from a folder by matching names from available in Dataframe

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a data frame named "Names_and_Nicks" and I need to take unique name NickName and read all three Param Names against that NickName. Then match those Param Names in a folder and load those .csv files in RStudio. 
My DataFrame is as follows:

[image]

And my Files look like this in folder:
[image]

So any suggestions and help will be great.

Comment: Split the data frame by nickname, then aggregate all three files for each nickname into a single data frame to output.

Comment: How to read files from folder by matching file names available in data-frame this is what I don't know. Can you please update me with 2,3 line script to perform this operation @Tim.

Comment: What is your actual desired output here?  One CSV file for each nickname, or something else?

Comment: As you can see from my data frame, against every nickname there are 3 .csv files (2015,2016,2017). I want to iterarte through nick_names list and load all files available against each nick name into RStudio by matching nick_names against Param_Names (Param_Names are csv file names)

Comment: Load into RStudio is rather vague term.  My answer below "loads" files sharing a common nickname into separate dataframes.  Maybe this is enough for what you need.

Comment: Yup, Its a bit vague, and Ya it's enough..Thank you so much Tim..!

Answer (score 1):

You can split your dataframe on the nickname, which will yield a list of dataframes, each one corresponding the files associated with a single nickname.  Then, you can iterate over each such dataframe and generate a single dataframe which is an aggregate of all the files for that nickname.  Something like this:

```
read_and_combine <- function(x) {
    result <- NULL
    for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
        new_df <- read.csv(file=x$ParamName[i], header=TRUE, sep=",")
        if (is.null(result)) {
            result <- new_df
        }
        else {
            result <- rbind(result, new_df)
        }
    }

    return(result)
}

df_list <- split(Names_and_Nicks, Names_and_Nicks$NickName)
df_combined <- lapply(df_list, read_and_combine)
```

At this point `df_combined` should be a list of dataframes, each of which contains rows for all the files corresponding to a single nickname.

Comment: df_list is of type list and function isn't accepting it. nrow(df_list) returns NULL

Comment: Why are you taking `nrow` on a list?  Lists don't have rows.  Did you try my _exact_ code or did you mess around with it?

Comment: nope, I used exactly your's one but it was taking alot of time so I tried something else, Ya I know List dont have any nrow.. Now testing yours one on small data set